# PPA for unity-tweak-tool-daily gives error when running apt-get update (404 Not Found)

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, updates, ppa

When I type the command: `sudo apt-get update`, I got the error below:

```
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Here is a full output of my command:

[image: command output]

I would like to get rid of this error and install Unity Tweak Tool in the easiest way possible.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu20.04LTS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file). http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu/dists/ does not have any packages for 20.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unity tweak tool](https://launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool) is already in the official ubuntu repository, look:

```
$ apt search unity tweak tool

unity-tweak-tool/focal,focal 0.0.7+-0ubuntu6 all
  configuration tool for the Unity desktop environment
```

Then you don't need anymore to have their repository installed. You can remove it from the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory or its specific line from /etc/sources.list file.
If you don't know how to remove the file or edit the file just ask.
After that simply update again your installation with

```
# apt update
```

or

```
$ sudo apt update
```

Comment: You mean that I need to remove 'freyja-dev-ubuntu-unity-tweak-tool-daily-focal.list' and 'freyja-dev-ubuntu-unity-tweak-tool-daily-focal.list.save' from sources.list.d folder?

Comment: OK! I know what happens and solved it. Thank you so much!